# Copy selected list of folders in gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, copy

I am trying to copy a list of selected folders and its content from a directory using gulp. Here is what I want

source

```
src/folder1
src/folder2
src/folder3
src/folder4
src/folder5
src/folder6
```

Dest

I should be able to loop through selected folders
var selected = ['folder1', 'folder3', 'folder6'];

Output should be with its content

```
dest/folder1
dest/folder3
dest/folder6
```

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md

Comment: Do you want the var selected to be dynamic?  It will change based on other functions or are all those folders known ahead of time?

Comment: Souce folder is just an array of hardcoded values. Static would help.